# Intercept http request from WebView on Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, webview

Is there a way to intercept an http request on Windows Phone 8?

I have a PhoneGap application that I would like to intercept some of the http requests that the WebView is making and return my own responses.  I am intercepting calls that are requesting assets on a web server and returning assets that are available to be generated locally.

In Android I can use [shouldInterceptrequest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

In iOS I can use [NSURLProtocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

From what I can tell on Windows Phone 8 I can register my own scheme to launch my app but I cannot intercept http requests.  Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for Windows Phone 8.

However there are new capabilities in Windows Phone 8.1: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/17/whats-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1/

Take a look at the section: Custom URI resolving

The post is about Windows 8.1, but there is sample code for Windows Phone 8.1 too: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7/ (Scenario 4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately from what I can tell the "Custom Uri Resolving" in Window Phone 8.1 uses UriToStreamResolver which looks to be a way to load an entire page from custom assets, and I am most interested in intercepting image requests and returning my own image data, which I don't see how I can do that using UriToStreamResolver.

Comment: You could put the phone in WiFi only. Then snoop http packets using wireshark from a different computer (machine-a) Note: you might have to run a web proxy on maxhine-a and point the phone there.

Comment: Sorry for the Delay. I confirm that i was wrong. There is no easy way of intercepting WebView requests. I think there are two possibilites: 1) Get the HTML content of webpage and parse it manually. 2) This one i didn't try, but when I met the problems with local images in windows 8 webview, I've found that link article:http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=492 Maybe this could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.  I haven't created a phonegap app so I'm not sure if you can reference the WebBrowser object on your page. If you can, you can use the "Navigating" event of the webbrowser to have a *VERY* limited look into the request. The NavigatingEventArgs argument contains the Uri of the request but that's about it. If there are specific uri's that you are looking for, you can always cancel the navigation and redirect the webbrowser to something else.